# Convert function to table values

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to remember the name of the method for finding a discrete function from its derivative. I want to create a table of values by difference equations. (not by step on the x or y axis)

http://postimg.org/image/pv6u5luhb/

P.s. sorry for my english!